# Reduction of two recursive languages

Tags: formal-languages

I'd like to ask if this implication holds, I have no idea how to prove/disprove it.

A is regular B is recursive $\implies$ $ A \le_m B$

Comment: What does $\le_m$ mean?

Comment: @xavierm02 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction#Formal_languages

Comment: @xavierm02 edited question, made a typo

Comment: From what I understand, you think that a regular (=simple?) language can be kind of embedded in a recursive (=complex?) one. It feels wrong because even though it can be as "complex" as recursive, it could also be way simpler. So (without really knowing what this is about), I'd try to find a very simple language B to provide a couterexample.

Comment: I would feel more likely to be true if you added that B can't be regular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rigorously, the answer is **no**. If the language $B$ is trivial (empty or complement of empty), no non-trivial language can be many-one reduced to it.

Practically, if $B$ is any non-trivial language, $A$ can even be recursive and the implication would still be true. In order to see why, note that the reduction $\leq_m$ has full power of recursive functions available to itself -- so it can find whether a particular word belongs to $A$ or not and, depending on that, produce either a fixed word from $B$ or a fixed word from complement of $B$. Thus, the structure of $B$ does not really matter if $A$ is recursive, as long as it can provide both "yes" and "no" answers for $\leq_m$.